# Github without pull requests

Tags: git, github, merge, fork

I have the following situation:

- A software hosted at github.
- 4 developers, each have his own fork in github.
- Each developer creates and develops using branches in his own fork.

Given that we use branches to develop, we want to merge our branches (in our forks) to the upstream repo. How do I merge in github without using pull request? Is it possible to merge to upstream from my own fork?

Comment: Do you have good reasons for 1) not using pull requests, and 2) using forks instead of branching directly off the main repo?

Comment: 1) Actually not. I was only thinking about the necessity to use pull request. We are only 3 developer, maybe the use of pull request could be a lot bureaucratic. 2) We only decided to use forks, pull requests wasn't in our minds when we thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push upstream master`

Replacing `upstream` with whatever you named your github remote, and `master` with the branch on github you want to push to.

If you don't currently have a remote pointing at the shared repo, you may need to do 
`git remote add upstream {url}`

**edit in response to comment**

If you want to merge branches, do that in your local repository first:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch
git push upstream master
```

Comment: I tried the command you recommend me and it shows me: "Everything up-to-date". I used this command from the branch I want to merge to upstream master. Thanks!